# Only allowing up to three digit numeric characters in a text box

Tags: c#, textbox, character, numeric, keystroke

Is there a way to only allow a user to input a maximum number of characters into a text box? I want the user to input a mark/grade and only be able to input 0 - 100. Below I have code that monitors the keystroke and only allows for numbers to be input, but I want to find a way to only allow the user to input a number with a minimum value of 0 and a maximum of 100.

```
private void TxtMark4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9' || e.KeyChar == ' ')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

or I could use the following:

```
if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57 || e.KeyChar == ' ')
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You Can Only Enter A Number!");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But I would like to find a way to only allow three characters to be input maximum.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Asp.Net?

Comment: Silverlight? Windows Phone?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is as simple as:

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 3;
```

Then you handle the maximum value on the Leave event:

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        int i = Convert.ToInt16(s);

        if (i > 100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number greater than 100");
            (sender as TextBox).Focus();
        }
    }
```

or

You could also use **System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown** where you can easily setup minimum and maximum.

Comment: YES! That works, but the three characters could then be 0 - 999 whereas I want to limit it between 0 - 100

Comment: @densgirl4 and now you know why you should use NumericUpDown instead of a text box when you want to input a number.

Comment: yes I do! I'm a student and know next to nothing on an advanced level in regards to C#. Wasn't even aware a control like NumericUpDown existed until I posted this question. I still have a LOT to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This version set textBox1.Text to empty string if fail to parse

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int i;

    textBox1.Text=
        false==int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out i)||0>i||i>100
            ?""
            :i.ToString();
}
```

If you want to keep the partial successfully parsed number then

```
String previousText="";

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var currentText=textBox1.Text;
    int i;

    textBox1.Text=
        int.TryParse(currentText, out i)
            ?0>i||i>99
                ?previousText
                :i.ToString()
            :""==currentText?currentText:previousText;

    previousText=textBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this with catch for every possible user error.

I'm assuming you textbox is named TxtMark4. Write txtMark4.Content() or what ever you need to read the content of the textbox in your framework in the if-test which does the TryParse

```
private void TxtMark4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int? tmp = null; //signed to allow it to be assigned the value of null
    if(int.TryParse(txtMark4.Text,out tmp)){
        if(tmp >=0 && tmp <= 100){
        //Here the number is between 0 and 100
        }
        else{//Number is below 0 or above 100
            if(tmp > 100){
                TxtMark4.Text = TxtMark4.Text.remove(2); //This will forcefully make it less or equal to 100
                DisplayLabel.text = "Numbers between 0-100 only";
            }
            else{
                TxtMark4.Text = ""; //and if its below 0 it will not be displayed
                DisplayLabel.text = "Numbers between 0-100 only";
            }
        }
    }
    else{//Not a number
        //Return some indicator to the user
        DisplayLabel.text = "numbers only";
    }
}
```